# Create Apex trigger on an Object than execute a Platform event

Tags: apex, trigger, platform-event

I`m trying to create an Apex Trigger on an Object (Asset for example) to check if a specific Checkbox fields is true than execute a platform event (which I have a PE flow that updates the record)

I got this code, seems like I didn't call the event correctly-

```
trigger AssetTest on Asset (before insert) {
for(Asset asse : Trigger.New) {
    if(asse.Entitlements__c == true){
     EventBus.publish(TestAsset__e)
    }
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to publish `TestAsset__e` ?

Comment: Nothing, just to execute it in order to trigger the related PE flow.

Comment: It does not work like that you need to create the object and pass details to it and then publish. For eg: 

   `ErrorLog__e errorLog = new ErrorLog__e();
    errorLog.Stacktrace__c = e.getStackTraceString();
    EventBus.publish(errorLog);`

Comment: There isn't a possibility to make the PE listen to the change triggered by the apex trigger condition? any chance you can provide an example with the one I gave? thanks!

Comment: If you implement a Flow instead of an Apex trigger when your object is changed, you can create a Platform Event without code. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_publish_flow.htm

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a platform event record, not just reference the platform event type. Change the publish call something like:

```
EventBus.publish(new TestAsset__e());
```

If your event doesn't contain any field values and you will simply do a query in the flow to discover the `Asset` records that need processing, you should ensure you only ever publish a single platform event in your transactions.

You can do this with a simple static Boolean variable (defaulted to false) in a helper class and use it in your logic called from your trigger something like:

```
if(asse.Entitlements__c && !Helper.alreadyPublished){
    EventBus.publish(new TestAsset__e());
    Helper.alreadyPublished = true;
}
```

Such boolean flags are often an anti-pattern in triggers, but work fine for this use case where the event *content* isn't important, just that one is raised to result in processing.

Make sure the event publish behaviour is after commit to avoid sending it too early when processing bulk asset creation.